# Diferencias entre const y readonly en C#

Tags: c#, variables, readonly, const

### **Esta pregunta es autorespondida**

¿Cuáles son las las diferencias que existen entre **const** y **readonly**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Las **constantes** son campos cuyos valores se establecen en tiempo de compilación y nunca se pueden cambiar. El uso de **constantes** permite que el código sea más legible y fácil de mantener. Cuando se usa una **constante** se les da un valor en su declaración, ejemplo:

```
const double PI = 3.14;
```

Si la **constante PI** se encuentra en varios lugares del código y necesitamos cambiar su valor, solamente tendríamos que ir al lugar donde se declaró y cambiar ahí su valor, ahorrándonos tener que realizar el cambio en varios lugares del código fuente donde se hace uso de **PI**.

El valor de una **constante** no puede cambiar, por lo que si una vez declarada la **constante PI** y asignado su valor intentamos cambiar su valor:

```
PI = 3.1415;
```

El compilador emitirá un error.

Por otra parte una **variable de solo lectura** tiene cierto parecido a una **constante** y se declara como:

```
readonly double PI = 3.14;
```

Efectivamente al igual que una **constante** su valor no se puede cambiar, excepto dentro de un **constructor**, ya que los atributos de una clase que sean **readonly** pueden ser modificados mientras se haga esta modificación dentro del **constructor de la clase**, ejemplo:

```
class Matematica
{
    readonly double PI = 3.14;

    public Matematica()
    {
        PI = 3.1415;
    }

    public void CambiarValor()
    {
        PI = 3.1; //Aquí ocurrirá un error de compilación 
    }
}
```

Aquí se declara la **variable readonly PI** y se le asigna un valor de inicialización. Dentro del constructor se le cambia su valor y todo marcha bien, pero cuando intentamos un cambio fuera del constructor de la clase, tal como ocurre dentro del **método CambiarValor**, el compilador lanzará un error, diciendo que este cambio no puede realizarse.

Esto nos puede ser útil para inicializar una **variable readonly** con un valor pasado como parámetro al constructor y que después de que se inicialice su valor no cambie más en el código:

```
public Matematica(double valor)
{
   PI = valor;
}
```

Otra diferencia que hay entre **constantes** y **variables readonly**, es que las **constantes** son miembros estáticos de la clase, es decir se puede acceder al valor de **PI** sin necesidad de construir un objeto de la clase.

```
public class Matematica
{
    public const double PI = 3.14;
}

Console.WriteLine(Matematica.PI);
```

No hace falta construir un objeto para tener acceso al **campo PI**, ya que este campo es de la clase, si hiciéramos:

```
var x = new Matematica();

Console.WriteLine(x.PI);
```

ocurriese un error de compilación ya que **PI** no le pertenece al objeto sino a la clase.

Por otra parte las **variables readonly** no son estáticas por defecto y si hay que construir un objeto para acceder a ellas:

```
public class Matematica
{
    public readonly double PI = 3.14;
}

var x = new Matematica();

Console.WriteLine(x.PI);
```

Por otra parte las **constantes** se compilan como literales, es decir cuando se compila el código, el compilador detecta que se están utilizando constantes y como una **constante** no puede cambiar su valor, lo que hace el compilador es sustituir en cualquier lugar que se encuentre el identificador de la **constante** por su valor literal, es decir si **PI** es una **constante**, internamente el compilador sustituirá **PI** por el valor con que fue inicializada, cada vez que encuentre **PI** pondrá **3.14**, por ejemplo. Esto último no ocurre con las **variables de solo lectura**.